Credit Risk Economic Capital
I'm trying to estimate the loss distribution due to change to in credit ratings of a bond. I'm doing a MC simulation using the credit ratings transition matrix and estimating the loss if the rating downgrades.
Loss is estimated as duration*(change in spread due to rating change). Now, do I need to use forward spreads here? As the loss is estimated for 1-year time horizon?

I think its up to personal preference from a modelling standpoint.
